# Error even after changing datatype in both dataset and SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a database and then a dataset in C# Visual Studio. In the database there is a table with a column called `CardType`. This was created by someone before me. And the value in this column is always 40. So he created it of type double.

I was told now that now the value has to be changed to SAR40 and not just 40. So now it is a string. So when I changed the value to SAR40 obviously there will be error when trying to add SAR40 to a column of type double. So first I went to SQL Server Management Studio and changed the type to nvarchar there. Then I come back to Visual Studio and changed the type of datatype of `CardType` to `System.String`.

Then when I run the program I still get an error

> Parameter value could not be converted from string to double.
> FormatException: The input string is in the wrong format.

How the program works is there are a bunch of small sections to fill data and each of the data goes into the database. Data like cardtype, hardwarerevision etc. And from this it will form a workrow.

```
workRow["CardType"] = type.Text;
workRow["Hardwarerevision"] = hw.Text;
```

and then finally add to the database using these two lines

```
//add new data row
ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow);
//write data to database
DataGridAdapter_CPU.Update(workRow);
```

So why do I still get an error?

I try to run the program with just 40 and the program is showing no error. It works fine. How is that possible. Because I changed both in the SQL Server Management Studio and dataset in Visual Studio to string type. So here it should show error. But it is not showing error. Whereas I try to enter SAR40 then it is showing error that you cant convert string to double. What could be the error reason? Kindly help me. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you have not changed the type on all required places, sure you forgot some place.

Comment: The few lines of code you supplied here do not provide enough information. Try providing more snippets from your code, and add more detail from the error message.

Comment: Well, the most obvious steps are: Make sure you really are changing the type in the correct database and table. Make sure to actually save the changes. Make sure you change the type in the program in all the relevant places. Other than that, there's not enough information to give a more specific answer.

Comment: *`workRow["CardType"] = type.Text;`* = Someone went to all the effort of making a dataset, then threw it away when they started coding, by reverting to stringly-typed style. Nice

Comment: I just tried storing data into the database directly using SSMS and used the value SAR40 and it worked there. So the value has been changed from double to string there in the correct database. So the problem is in c# program. I double checked cardtype and it is string and I have saved it. I even hower my over that workRow["CardType"] = type.Text;, it is showing cardtype is of string. Now the error is coming in this line -  DataGridAdapter_CPU.Update(workRow);. So do I have to make some other changes in Datagridadapter_CPU. So what should I do to correct the error happening here. Thank You.

Comment: Code should be `workRow.CardType` not `workRow["CardType"]`, plus all the other errors  (`ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow)` should be `ds.UNIO_CPU.AddUNIO_CPURow(workRow)` etc etc) - seems original author didn't understand strongly typed datasets much

Comment: Make sure you've saved your schema and run the custom tool on the dataset, and that the parameter collections have changed type for the CardType parameters

Comment: Please check my above comment. The error is at DataGridAdapter_CPU.Update(workRow). The rest works perfectly fine. When I tried to run the program and enter SAR40 and click save, it will show the error                               System.Format.Exception : Parameter value could not be converted from string to double.
FormatException: The input string is in the wrong format and this error shows up right next to DataGridAdapter_CPU.Update(workRow). So this is where the error occurs. Kindly do help me on why is that. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what are the nature of the objects from your post. Also, it is not obvious where exception happens. From your sample, is it OK on string

```
ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow);
```

And fails on

```
DataGridAdapter_CPU.Update(workRow);
```

Right?
And can you provide more details about DataGridAdapter_CPU?

In addition, DataSet contains DataTable with its own structure, did you check it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just check once again by running the program but commented out DataGridAdapter_CPU.Update(workRow); and kept ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow); as normal and ran the program. Obviously the data was not stored in the database but the program ran correctly without any error. Yes the error is happening at ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow); What additional details do you need regarding the DataGridAdapter_CPU.  Also I didnt understand the question "DataSet contains DataTable with its own structure, did you check it?". I am not an experienced in this. I just know basics of c#.

Comment: Well, DataSet has property Tables (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.tables?view=net-5.0) which is type of DataTable (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0). My suggestion is to debug 'ds.UNIO_CPU' which supposed to be a DataTable and iterate through its DataColumnCollection where you can check the internal type of each column. Also, what is the type of DataGridAdapter_CPU? So what happens 'kept ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow); as normal and ran the program.' or 'the error is happening at ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow)' ?

Comment: Workrow is the name of the datarow. So you create an instance of a row of the table - DataRow workRow = ds.UNIO_CPU.NewUNIO_CPURow();.    Then u add the different elements into the work row and then you add it into the dataset. That is ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow). DataGridAdapter_CPU is the table adapter. So when I run just ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow) and comment out the next part the new row gets added to the dataset in VB but is then not uploaded to the sqlserver. There is no error happening at ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow). I hope this is good clarification.

Comment: So 'ds.UNIO_CPU.Rows.Add(workRow)' doesn't throw an exception. You may also check the dataType for DataRow.Table.Columns. E.g.:
foreach(DataColumn column in workRow.Table.Columns){Console.WriteLine(column.DataType); }.

But I suppose you need to research 'DataGridAdapter_CPU' and the way it maps DataRow.

Comment: I just checked foreach(DataColumn column in workRow.Table.Columns). And it shows all of them as System.string.

Comment: I finally got it working. But I still dont know what the problem is. How I got it working is delete the CardType column from the dataset and then create a new column called CardType which is of string type and configuring TableAdapter again. This solved the problem.

Comment: I found out the problem. I went to the old copy of the program which had the old CardType which was changed from double to string and there I reconfigured the table adapter again, and it worked.  So changing in the table in VB and SSMS is not just enough. I need to configure the change in table adapter as well. That was my mistake.

Comment: Nice! Good luck!)